# How to load json url and get data using python

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy, request

I want to load this api [url](https://gestion.lffs.eu/lms_league_ws/public/api/v1/club/byMyLeague?filter=&club_status_id=1&page=2&pagination=21) and fetch data. I am using this code to get this but i am getting 400 bad request.
Actual website link is (https://www.lffs.eu/les-clubs/)

'''

```
import urllib, json


enter code hereurl = "https://gestion.lffs.eu/lms_league_ws/public/api/v1/club/byMyLeague?filter=&club_status_id=1&page=2&pagination=21"

response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
print(data)
```

'''

Comment: The API expects a token. You need to first generate the token.

Comment: how to generate the token.?

Comment: Probably you need to login with a username and password, and the server returns the token

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the way you used the API. If you run it on Google you will see the error. The API expects some kind of token from you. Make sure you provide it first.

Comment: Is there any other way to grab the data?